# Movilizer - Trigger sync on movelet end

Tags: mobile, movilizer

A partner is asking me if the following code is OK, since it is not triggering the forced synchronization upon pressing OK. I am not able to identify the issue. He tested on iOS and Swing.

```
 <question type="0" title="MUVE" key="Q(Sync)">
                       <answer action="FULLSYNC" position="1" nextQuestionKey="END" key="Q(Sync)_ans" labelFontSize="VERYLARGE" labelFontStyle="BOLD" columnSizeType="ROWS" labelAlignment="CENTER">
                              <text> ¿Seguro que quiere guardar todos los canvios del dia?</text>
                       </answer>
                       <onEnterAssignment>
                              setCustomizingProperty($customizing:'screen.footer.ok.text', 'Guardar');
                              setCustomizingProperty($customizing:'screen.footer.back.text', 'Atras');
                       </onEnterAssignment>
                </question>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code looks perfect. The two important details to achieve the asked functionality are:

- action="FULLSYNC"
- nextQuestionKey="END"

both looks fine in the definition you provided.